# ¿Cómo subir archivos de tipo imagen y pdf en React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy tratando de realizar un input en React.js para guardar múltiples imágenes y un input para seleccionar un pdf, pero no encuentro la forma de guardar múltiples imágenes en una variable y un pdf en otra variable para luego ser enviada para guardarse en la bd. usando FormData

Alguien sabe una forma de guardar múltiples imágenes en una variable para luego solo mandarlas a guardar a la BD?

Comment: Hola @david-vasquez, deberías editar tu pregunta agregando un poco del código que has intentado para ver tus avances y así ayudarte mejor!

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberías crear tu input

```
 <input type="file" />
```

Después asignarle una función cuando exista un cambio en este input para guardarla en un estado el array de las direcciones donde estan tus imagenes en local

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
```

---

```
      <input
          type="file"
          value={selectedFile}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}
        />
```

Dependiendo del index de los elementos que selecciones "files[0] 1 , 2 , 3"  general mente lo mejor es crear un .map para el envió de cada uno de los elementos a lo cual generalmente un servidor responde con una promesa

por ultimo para esperar que todas las promesas sean respondidas antes de darle una respuesta al usuario puedes utilizar Promise.all

Encuentra mas informacion [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)